# raise errorclass, errorvalue _mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: cursor closed in Python 2.7

Tags: python, mysql, exception, cursor

I have following python function in the `run.py`

```
from emotion_classification_model import learningbased
import threading

 def run_code():

    threading.Timer(60.0, run_code).start()
    learningbased()

 run_code()
```

There is another `insert.py` file and it include with

```
import MySQLdb

conn =  MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",user="root",passwd="",db="chat_app",use_unicode=True,charset="utf8")
x = conn.cursor()

def insert_result(insert_emotion):

   x.execute('''INSERT into machinelearningresults (Emotion) values (%s)''', (insert_emotion))
  conn.commit()
  x.close()

def r_insert(rule_result):
  x.execute('''INSERT into rulebasedresults (Emotion) values (%s)''', (rule_result))
  conn.commit()
  x.close()
  conn.close()
```

When I call the `insert_result(insert_emotion)`and `r_insert(rule_result)` functions inside of the `learningbased()` function it makes following error.

```
raise errorclass, errorvalue _mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: cursor closed
```

Can anyone help me to fix this error.